# Unicode code points array is converted to String and back with changes

Tags: java, unicode

The array with defined Unicode code points is:

```
int[] unicodeDefinedCodePoints = IntStream
            .rangeClosed(Character.MIN_CODE_POINT, Character.MAX_CODE_POINT)
            .filter(Character::isDefined)
            .toArray();
```

Let's transform it to a String and back to code points:

```
int[] unicodeDefinedCodePointsAfterTransformation =
            new String(unicodeDefinedCodePoints, 0, unicodeDefinedCodePoints.length)
                .codePoints()
                .toArray();
```

I expected to get the same array but

1. the array after the transformation doesn't contain the code points 56319 and 56320
2. the code point 1113088 is duplicated after the transformation

The codes of code points above are decimal.

Used Java version is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.17.1) (build 1.8.0_275-b01 suse-1.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Pro tip: when talking about Unicode codepoints, it's almost always more useful to give the hex notation. 56319 is U+DBFF, 56320 is U+DC00 and 1113088 is U+10FC00. That alone should help you get started by looking up the definition of those codepoints. And no: I don't know what exactly is happening, but the fact that all of those are close to "round borders" makes me think there is some reason behind this madness.

Comment: The first two are surrogates, and the last one is private use.

Comment: What are you actually trying to acomplish in this, @Thed?

Comment: I need to test a lexer. There should be two tests, the first one with an input expected by the lexer, and therefore producing some tokens, and the second one with an input that's unexpected by the lexer. I need to check that lexer doesn't produce any tokens with an unexpected input. In order to make an unexpected input, I collect all defined Unicode code points in an array, remove expected code points, and then create a String of remaining code points. And it turned out that converting mentioned code points array to a String _at least may have_ such strange side effects. Will debug that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid Unicode code points are those between 0 (MIN_CODE_POINT) and 1114111 (MAX_CODE_POINT). However, code points between 55296 (MIN_SURROGATE) and 57343 (MAX_SURROGATE) are reserved for highSurrogates and lowSurrogates, which form pairs to represent characters whose code points are ranging between 65536 and 1114111 since 65535 is the greatest number that can be stored as 2-bytes char.
To get an array of all valid unicode code points, you must exclude surrogates as shown below.

```
int[] unicodeDefinedCodePoints = IntStream
     .rangeClosed(Character.MIN_CODE_POINT, Character.MAX_CODE_POINT)
     .filter((i) -> i < Character.MIN_SURROGATE || i > Character.MAX_SURROGATE)
     .toArray();
```

Array should include all of 1112064 valid code points.

Comment: Thanks Paweł! Finally got some time to read the standard. Surrogates, though are _assigned_ code points, cannot be assigned to an abstract character. Thus, a) they don't matter for applications processing _encoded_ textual data _independently on its encoding form_ and b) may lead to strange errors when converted to strings somehow. As usual, some things are named differently in the standard and in the code. 'Assigned' code points in the standard are named as 'defined' in the code. OK. There's `isSurrogate(char ch)`. Where's `isSurrogate(int i)`? As usual, I wonder.

Answer (score 3):

***No clear answer***

- 56319 is U+DBFF, private use high surrogate, last.
- 56320 is U+DC00, low surrogate, first.
- 1113088 isU+10FC00, invalid character.

It might be that high surrogate followed by low surrogate gets processed. And the invalid character is ofcourse a singleton black hole; the substitution character on failure.

For the surrogate pair, just walk decreasing, or make two Strings with one code point.

```
int[] unicodeDefinedCodePoints = IntStream
        .rangeClosed(-Character.MAX_CODE_POINT, -Character.MIN_CODE_POINT)
        .map(Math::abs)
        .filter(Character::isValidCodePoint)
        .toArray();
```

I do not think there is a diffence here between isDefined and isValidCodePoint, but the latter is more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the idea re surrogate pairs processing, I just recalled that I saw a similar approach in JDK. Looks like I need go a bit deeper and read the standard. 

As re the 1113088 (U+10FC00), `Character.isValidCodePoint()` returns `true` for it.
As re the difference between `isDefined` and `isValidCodePoint`, in my case, the first one returns 249704 code points, the last one gives 1114112 code points. That said, all code points in the MIN-to-MAX range are considered valid, but I need only those having some meaning.